# Excel VSTO how to know if AutoSave is On

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

Using c# in VSTO for Excel, how I know that AutoSave is On or Off? My document is on SharePoint so I need to force AutoSave true for all the users to see the last update doc.

Try:

```
ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False //dosen´t exist
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.AutoUpdateSaveChanges; //throws exception
```

Tks

Comment: Maybe it's because you do anything with the information ? What about `bool autoSaveEnabled = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.AutoUpdateSaveChanges;`?

Comment: throws exception

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: Is COM exception... Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC